# Check if window is on the current desktop?

Tags: python, pygtk

How do I check that a pygtk Window is on the current desktop?

A program I'm fixing has:

```
if self.pymp.window.get_property('visible'):
    self.pymp.window.hide()
else:
    self.pymp.window.move(self.pymp.position[0], self.pymp.position[1])
    self.pymp.window.show()
    self.pymp.window.present()
```

I want to replace:

```
if self.pymp.window.get_property('visible'):
```

With:

```
if self.pymp.window.get_property('visible') and window_is_on_current_workspace(self.pymp.window):
```

I can implement `window_is_on_current_workspace(window)` with `wnck` as:

```
def window_is_on_current_workspace(window):
    import wnck
    v = wnck.screen_get_default() # needed due to known bug
    xid = window.window.xid
    win = None
    while win is None:
        win = wnck.window_get(xid)
        if gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration()
    wor = win.get_screen().get_active_workspace()
    return win.is_on_workspace(wor)
```

And it works but it's icky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wnck. Here is a sample,

```py
from gi.repository import Wnck # import wnck for gtk2

screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()

def window_is_on_current_workspace(window):
    for win in screen.get_windows():
        if win.get_pid() == os.getpid(): # You could use other methods to determine if you've the right window, like window.name; Just make sure you can uniquely identify it
            return win.get_workspace() == s.get_active_workspace()

        # This works if you have only one window per process, it's just an example. You can use any method to match your gtk window with the x11 window returned by wnck.Screen
```

Comment: The whole loop can be replaced by `window.is_on_workspace(screen.get_active_workspace())`. No need to iterate over all the windows.